# How to fix sound output devices not showing up on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, soundcard

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. On recent startup only a Dummy Output shows up under sound Output Devices.

This has been happening for a while but usually the command `killall pulseaudio && pulseaudio --start` was always able to fix the problem.
Not so any more. In fact the soundcards don't seem to be found at all by the system:

```
aplay -l
```

returns

> aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

Any thoughts on what I should do?

EDIT:

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio` returns nothing

`pactl list short sinks` returns `0 auto_null   module-null-sink.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED`

`alsamixer` returns
`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`

Comment: Does `cat /proc/asound/cards` show anything? If yes, what is the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`?

Comment: `cat /proc/asound/cards` returns :
`cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory` and `ls -l /dev/snd/` returns
`total 0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 mei 22 12:21 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 mei 22 12:21 timer`

Comment: What sound device(s) do you have?

Comment: @CL just the internal speakers of my laptop (A Dell Inspiron 15, 5000 series)

Comment: What happens when you try to run `modprobe snd-hda-intel` as root?

Comment: It doesn't return anything `root@Vendetta:~# modprobe snd-hda-intel`
`root@Vendetta:~# `

Comment: Run `rmmod snd-hda-intel`, then `modprobe snd-hda-intel`, then check `/var/log/messages` (or the output of `dmesg`) for new error messages.

Comment: Nothing in the logs

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal commands `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio`, `aplay -l`, and `pactl list short sinks`? Please also make sure that the relevant audio channels in `alsamixer` (terminal) or `gnome-alsamixer` (GUI) have their volume turned up and aren’t muted. Thanks.

Comment: If it doesn't even appear in the `lspci` output, then you have disabled it in the BIOS options, or there is a hardware problem.